# Lifetime in mutable structure with HashSet

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having trouble understanding why rust doesn't like my remove_str method in there:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashSet;


#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct StringWrap<'a>{
    s: &'a String,
}

struct Container<'a>{
    m: HashSet<StringWrap<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Container<'a>{
    fn remove_str(&mut self, s: &str){
        let string = String::from(s);
        let to_remove = StringWrap{s: &string};
        self.m.remove(&to_remove);
    }
}
```

It chokes with:

```
error[E0597]: `string` does not live long enough
  --> tests/worksheet.rs:17:39
   |
14 | impl<'a> Container<'a>{
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
17 |         let to_remove = StringWrap{s: &string};
   |                                       ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |         self.m.remove(&to_remove);
   |         ------------------------- argument requires that `string` is borrowed for `'a`
19 |     }
   |     - `string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

As far as I can see, my `string` and `to_remove` live long enough to allow the `.remove` call to do its job. Is it because remove is potentially asynchronous or something like that?

Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: Why do you have lifetimes in the first place? It seems to be because you are using `s: &String` in your `StringWrap` struct, but that shouldn't be necessary -- just use `s: String`, then you don't need lifetimes at all.

Comment: I think this is a very good question. I don't know why it got a downvote and a `close` vote. It's clear the `HashSet` could have contained owned strings, but the OP asked for help to better understand *why* this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I can see, my string and to_remove live long enough to allow the .remove call to do its job. Is it because remove is potentially asynchronous or something like that?

No, it's because [`HashSet::remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.remove) must be called with something that the item becomes when borrowed:

```rust
pub fn remove<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, value: &Q) -> bool
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

However, unless you manually implement [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) for `StringWrap`, only [the blanket reflexive implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#impl-Borrow%3CT%3E-4) will apply—and thus `remove` can only be called with `value` of type `&StringWrap<'a>`.  Note the lifetime requirement.

What you need to do to make this work is to implement `Borrow` for `StringWrap`.  You could, for example, do the following:

```rust
impl Borrow<str> for StringWrap<'_> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        self.s
    }
}
```

and then `Container::remove_str` can merely forward its argument to `HashMap::remove`:

```rust
impl Container<'_> {
    fn remove_str(&mut self, s: &str) {
        self.m.remove(s);
    }
}
```

[See it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=523a16c500a254c30990f93a99a86ce5).

All that said, it's rather unusual to store references in a `HashSet`: typically one would move ownership of the stored `String`s into the set, which would render this problem moot as no lifetimes would be at play.

Comment: That's interesting. It got me thinking why `remove` expects a `&Q` instead of `&T`, but I decided to post a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70979354/why-does-hashsetremove-accept-a-q-ref-as-a-parameter).

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I have references is because I have a large amount of primary data (strings basically), and several hashsets containing various sets of them, so I don't want to duplicate those strings all the time.

Comment: In that case, you might find that storing `Rc<String>` is almost as efficient whilst still avoiding the lifetime shenanigans.

Comment: Also, `&String` should (almost?) always be `&str` (`Rc<str>` is also a good candidate, BTW).

Answer (score -1):

In context of HashSet<T>::remove/take/get(arg1: &Q):
These call internally will try to get "T's borrowed version Q from inside the HashSet<T> itself" to compare to arg1 by Borrow<Q> trait for T. So a custom `impl Borrow<Q> for T` with appropriate lifetime is a good idea.

Comment: What does this add over the excellent existing answer?