# Why does HashSet::remove() accept a &Q as a parameter?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The `HashSet` type is a generic over `T`, but its `remove` method expects a parameter of type `&Q` `where T: Borrow<Q>`:

```
pub fn remove<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, value: &Q) -> bool
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

Why doesn't it simply expect a `&T`?

Comment: that way is even more generic, the borrow is done by the function for whatever type instead of manually do it each time you call it.

Comment: ...and because `Borrow` has [a blanket reflexive implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#impl-Borrow%3CT%3E-4), providing an `&T` will always work.

Comment: As a concrete example: If `T` was `String`, you wouldn't be able to call `my_set.remove("foo")` if the parameter was `&T == &String`, but clearly allocating a `String` here is not necessary.

Comment: If a `HashSet` contains `String`, it would be annoying to have to `to_owned()` a `&str` to remove a functionally equal value from the `HashSet`. By only requiring that the value-to-remove be borrowable as `&T` you can remove values by equality without needing to do the cloning that would be necessary to make the types work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, guys! I'll try to elaborate on that and describe it in more detail for other readers.

In Rust it is very common to write a function with a `&str` param, which allows us to call it not only by passing `&str` but also `&String` (thanks to what is known as [Deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)). However, if we have a `HashSet<String>`, that kind of "magic" conversion wouldn't be possible if its `remove` method was expecting a `&String` and we tried to call it with a `&str`. To better illustrate that, here is an example:

```
fn f1(s: &str) {
    println!("{s}");
}

fn f2(s: &String) {
    println!("{s}");
}

fn main() {
    let string: String = "A string".to_string();
    f1(&string);  // This is OK (Deref coercion)
    f2(&string);  // This is OK
    let str_ref: &str = "A str ref";
    f1(str_ref);  // This is OK
    f2(str_ref);  // This does NOT compile
}
```